# How to play an animation as long as an object is colliding with another in Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, phaser-framework, matter.js

I'm creating a game with Phaser 3, specifically with the Matter physics engine. I want an animation to play only while an object is colliding with another.

Code for the object (the variable `bench` is declared before the `create()` function)

```
//Place a bench
bench = this.matter.add.sprite(2000, 200, 'sheet', 'bench', {shapes: shapes.bench});
bench.setScale(2, 1);
bench.setPosition(2250 + bench.centerOfMass.x, 200 + bench.centerOfMass.y);
//Needed this again so that bench can detect collisions
bench.isSensor(true);
```

Current code

```
//Detect collision when we are on the bench, so we can play the grind animation
this.matter.world.on('collisionstart', function (grindNow, skater, bench) {
    grind = true;
});
```

The problem is, the code above still logs `true` to the console when the player is colliding with the ground and I only want to detect collisions with the `bench` object here. I've tried just playing the animation inside the function, which doesn't work either. I've also tried

```
if (this) {
   grind = true;
}
else {
   grind = false;
}
```

and then tried to use that variable to decide when to play the grinding animation, but that didn't help either. Lastly, I've tried playing the animation inside the create function, which would always return `undefined` even though the animation had been created.

I've tried setting a variable inside that function and only playing

Comment: Is your code updated in your github repo? I might take a look later this weekend.

Comment: @ManuelAbascal yes. It isn’t the exact code as the one above but it is up to date

Comment: I just need to have the same code base that you currently have so I can debug it easily. I'll probably do it later on the weekend. :)

Comment: @ManuelAbascal I can update it in about 7 hours when I get off work. There’s no major differences, I was just trying different ways to get it to work

Comment: @ManuelAbascal just double checked, and it is current

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution, although I don't know if you want to use it. I found **[this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phaser-matter-collision-plugin)** that makes it easier to manage collisions with **[Phaser](https://phaser.io/phaser3)**.

Follow these steps:

- **First**, add this line **`<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser-matter-collision-plugin"></script>`** in your **`game_index.html`** file like so:

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser-matter-collision-plugin"></script>
<script src= "skateboarding.js" ></script>
<script src = "archery.js"></script>
<script src = "soccer.js"></script>
```

If you want to install it in a different way, read the **[full installation guide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phaser-matter-collision-plugin#installation)**.

- **Second**, in the **`config`** object add this code snippet:

```
plugins: {
    scene: [
        {
            plugin: PhaserMatterCollisionPlugin, // The plugin class
            key: "matterCollision", // Where to store in Scene.Systems, e.g. scene.sys.matterCollision
            mapping: "matterCollision" // Where to store in the Scene, e.g. scene.matterCollision
        }
    ]
},
```

Now, your **`config`** object should look like this:

```
//Game configurations
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 1500, //<-- this is the width of what we will see at one time
    height: gameHeight,
    physics: physicsConfig,
    plugins: {
        scene: [
            {
                plugin: PhaserMatterCollisionPlugin, // The plugin class
                key: "matterCollision", // Where to store in Scene.Systems, e.g. scene.sys.matterCollision
                mapping: "matterCollision" // Where to store in the Scene, e.g. scene.matterCollision
            }
        ]
    },
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update
    }   
}
```

**Third**, remove these code snippet:

```
//Detect the player's collision with the ground
this.matter.world.on('collisionstart', function (onGround, skater, ground) {
    //If the player is touching the ground, set this value to true
    skaterTouchingGround = true;
});

//Detect collision when we are on the bench, so we can play the grind animation
this.matter.world.on('collisionstart', function (grindNow, skater, bench) {
    grind = true;
});
```

**Fourth**, on the same place where you removed the previous code snippets add these code blocks:

```
//Detect the player's collision with the ground
this.matterCollision.addOnCollideStart({
    objectA: skater,
    objectB: ground,
    callback: () => skaterTouchingGround = true
});

//Detect collision when we are on the bench, so we can play the grind animation
this.matterCollision.addOnCollideStart({
    objectA: skater,
    objectB: bench,
    callback: () =>  grind = true
});
```

Now, you should be able to get the **`grind`**'s value printed in the **`console`** when touching the **`player`** touches the **`bench`**.

**For your reference**, here is the entire code:

```
//Define our start button for out index page
var startButton = document.querySelector("#startSkate").addEventListener("click", () => {
    //Delay in ms to remove our button
    let removeDelay = 1;
    //Call function to start the game
    this.startSkateGame();
    //Call the setTimeout method and define a function
    setTimeout(function () {
        //Get elements and remove them to clear the page
        document.getElementById('startArch').remove();
        document.getElementById('startSkate').remove();
        document.getElementById('startSoccer').remove();
        document.getElementById('logo').remove();
        //Pass the delay
    }, removeDelay);
});

//Define the function that we call when our start button is clicked
startSkateGame = () => {

    //Configurations for the physics engine
    var physicsConfig = {
    default: 'matter',
    matter : {
        gravity: {
            x: 0,
            y: 2.5, // <--This is the only way I could get the skater to roll up the ramp.s
        },
        debug: true //CHANGE THIS TO TRUE TO SEE LINES
        }   
    }

    //Variables for height and width
    var gameHeight = 750;
    var gameWidth = 5000;

    //Game configurations
    var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 1500, //<-- this is the width of what we will see at one time
    height: gameHeight,
    physics: physicsConfig,
    plugins: {
        scene: [
          {
            plugin: PhaserMatterCollisionPlugin, // The plugin class
            key: "matterCollision", // Where to store in Scene.Systems, e.g. scene.sys.matterCollision
            mapping: "matterCollision" // Where to store in the Scene, e.g. scene.matterCollision
          }
        ]
      },
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update
    }   
    }

    /* This variable will be used to make sure the skater 
    cannot ollie while he is already in the air */
    var skaterTouchingGround;
    var grind;

    //Start the game
    var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

    //Declare variables so we can access them in all functions
    var skater;
    var ground;
    var sky;
    var bench;

    //Score variables
    let score = 0;
    let scoreBoard;

    function preload() {
    //Images
    this.load.image('sky', 'archery_assets/images/sky.png');

    //Load sprites from TexturePacker
    this.load.atlas('sheet', 'skate_assets/sprites.png', 'skate_assets/sprites.json');
    //Load body shapes from PhysicsEditor
    this.load.json('shapes', 'skate_assets/spritesPE.json');
    }

    function create() {

    //Background
    sky = this.add.image(2500, 325,'sky')
    //Scale the image
    sky.setDisplaySize(gameWidth, gameHeight);

    //Get the hitboxes
    var shapes = this.cache.json.get('shapes');

    //Set world bounds    
    this.matter.world.setBounds(0, 0, gameWidth, gameHeight);

    //Place ground object
    ground = this.matter.add.sprite(0, 0, 'sheet', 'ground', {shape: shapes.ground});
    //Ground is 600x600, so double the x pixels and we get screen width
    ground.setScale(8.5, 1);
    ground.setPosition(2500, 650);
    //Let the ground detect collisions 
    ground.isSensor(true);

    //Place the ramp
    var ramp = this.matter.add.sprite(0, 0, 'sheet', 'ramp', {shape: shapes.ramp});
    ramp.setPosition(550 + ramp.centerOfMass.x, 250 + ramp.centerOfMass.y);

    //Place a bench
    bench = this.matter.add.sprite(2000, 200, 'sheet', 'bench', {shapes: shapes.bench});
    bench.setScale(2, 1);
    bench.setPosition(2250 + bench.centerOfMass.x, 200 + bench.centerOfMass.y);
    //Needed this again so that bench can detect collisions
    bench.isSensor(true);

    //Create the skater
    skater = this.matter.add.sprite(0, 0, 'sheet', 'roll/0001', {shape: shapes.s0001});
    skater.setPosition(100 + skater.centerOfMass.x, 200 + skater.centerOfMass.y);

    //Collision filtering
    var staticCategory = this.matter.world.nextCategory();
    ramp.setCollisionCategory(staticCategory);
    ground.setCollisionCategory(staticCategory);
    bench.setCollisionCategory(staticCategory);

    //Skater needs to be in a different category
    var skaterCategory = this.matter.world.nextCategory();
    skater.setCollisionCategory(skaterCategory);

    //Roll animation
    //Generate the frame names
    var rollFrameNames = this.anims.generateFrameNames(
        'sheet', {start: 1, end: 4, zeroPad: 4,
        prefix: 'roll/'}
    );
    //Create the animation
    this.anims.create({
        key: 'roll', frames: rollFrameNames, frameRate: 16, repeat: -1
    });

    //Push animation
    var pushFrameNames = this.anims.generateFrameNames(
        'sheet', {start: 5, end: 8, zeroPad: 4,
        prefix: 'push/'}
    );
    this.anims.create({
        key: 'push', frames: pushFrameNames, frameRate: 16, repeat: 0 
    });

    //Shuvit animation
    var shuvFrameNames = this.anims.generateFrameNames(
        'sheet', {start: 9, end: 12, zeroPad: 4,
        prefix: 'shuv/'}
    );
    this.anims.create({
        key: 'shuv', frames: shuvFrameNames, frameRate: 32, repeat: 0 
    });

    //Ollie animation
    var ollieFrameNames = this.anims.generateFrameNames(
        'sheet', {start: 13, end: 20, zeroPad: 4,
        prefix: 'ollie/'}
    );
    this.anims.create({
        key: 'ollie', frames: ollieFrameNames, frameRate: 24, repeat: 0
    });

    //Kickflip animation
    var kfFrameNames = this.anims.generateFrameNames(
        'sheet', {start: 21, end: 33, zeroPad: 4,
        prefix: 'kickflip/'}
    );
    this.anims.create({
        key: 'kickflip', frames: kfFrameNames, frameRate: 24, repeat: 0
    });

    //Nosegrind  animation
    var ngFrameNames = this.anims.generateFrameNames(
        'sheet', {start: 34, end: 37, zeroPad: 4,
        prefix: 'nosegrind/'}
    );
    this.anims.create({
        key: 'nosegrind', frames: ngFrameNames, frameRate: 24, repeat: 0
    });

    //This keeps the rolling animation going once the push animation is done
    skater.on('animationcomplete', () => {
        skater.anims.play('roll');
    });

    //Input for arrowkeys
    this.arrowKeys = this.input.keyboard.addKeys({
        up: 'up',
        down: 'down',
        left: 'left',
        right: 'right'
    }); 

    //Input for WASD keys
    this.WASDkeys = this.input.keyboard.addKeys({
        W: 'W',
        A: 'A',
        S: 'S',
        D: 'D'
    });

    //Spacebar
    this.spacebar = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.SPACE);

    //Camera to follow the skater
    this.cameras.main.setBounds(0, 0, gameWidth, gameHeight);
    this.cameras.main.startFollow(skater);

    //Detect the player's collision with the ground
    this.matterCollision.addOnCollideStart({
        objectA: skater,
        objectB: ground,
        callback: () => skaterTouchingGround = true
    });

    //Detect collision when we are on the bench, so we can play the grind animation
    this.matterCollision.addOnCollideStart({
        objectA: skater,
        objectB: bench,
        callback: () =>  grind = true
    });

    //Create the scoreboard as a container
    scoreBoard = this.add.container(10, 50);
    //Add text to this container, displaying our score
    scoreText = this.add.text(10, 50, "SCORE: 0", {fontSize: '56px', color: '#fff'});

    //Add the text to the container which will be our scoreboard
    scoreBoard.add(scoreText);

    //Make the scoreboard follow the player
    this.tweens.add({
        targets: scoreBoard,
        ease: 'Linear',
        duration: 1,
        delay: 1,
        yoyo: false,
        repeat: -1
    });

    }

    function update() {
    console.log(skaterTouchingGround);
    //Set variable for player movement
    var pushSpeed = 0;
    var ollie = 0;

    //Make sure the player isn't doing anything if he's upside down, or crashed
    let skaterCrashed;

    //Variable to check the angle of the skater
    let angleOkay = skater.angle > -89 && skater.angle < 89;

    //Determine if the player is crashed or not
    if (angleOkay) {
        skaterCrashed = false;
    }
    else {
        skaterCrashed = true;
        window.alert("You crashed!");
    }

    //Starting parameter, as we don't want to do anything if we are crashed
    if (!skaterCrashed) {
        //Pushing
        if (Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.spacebar) && skaterTouchingGround) {
            //Increase speed
            pushSpeed = 15;

            //Move player
            skater.setVelocityX(pushSpeed);

            //Play push animation
            skater.anims.play('push');
        }

        //Ollie
        if (Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.arrowKeys.up) && skaterTouchingGround) {
            //Set this to false, because we are about to jump
            skaterTouchingGround = false;

            //Set ollie power
            ollie = -15;

            //Set skate velocity
            skater.setVelocityY(ollie);

            //Play the ollie animation
            skater.anims.play('ollie');

            //Scoring for ollie
            score += 1;
        }

        //Shuvit
        if (Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.arrowKeys.down)) {
            //Play the shuvit animation
            skater.anims.play('shuv');

            //Scoring for shuv
            score += 3;
        }

        //Kickflip
        if (Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.WASDkeys.W)  && skaterTouchingGround) {
            //Reset variable since we are jumping
            skaterTouchingGround = false

            //Set jump height
            ollie = -14

            //Move the player
            skater.setVelocityY(ollie);

            //Play animation
            skater.anims.play('kickflip');

            //Scoring for kickflip
            score += 10;
        }

        //Tilting backwards in the air
        if (this.arrowKeys.left.isDown && !skaterTouchingGround) {
            //Be able to turn backwards so you don't flip
            skater.angle -= 3 ;
        }
        //Tilting forwards in the air
        if (this.arrowKeys.right.isDown && !skaterTouchingGround) {
            //Be able to turn forwards so you don't flip
            skater.angle += 3 ;
        }
    }

    //Move the scoreboard
    scoreText.x = skater.body.position.x - 200;
    scoreText.setText("SCORE : " + score);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works great. Can you send me a message in a chat?

Comment: Side note- if I try to log ```grind```, I get ```undefined```

Comment: I fixed the undefined problem with the variable, however I still would like to chat. I don't know how to open a chat room

Comment: Here is the chat link: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202115/phaser-3-robert-manuel

How to create a chat: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315325/how-do-i-create-a-chat-room